# How is the reccurence of Max Heapify T(n)= T(2n/3) + $\theta(1)$?

Tags: heap-sort

I'm trying to figure out how is the recurrence of $maxheapify()$ is $T(n)=T(2n/3)+O(1)$

If size of max heap is $n$, then calling $maxheapify(A, 1)$ will (at worst case) go through only one element in each level (in the downwards direction) up to level $h$ (where $h = \log n$)

So, the recurrence should be $T(n) = T(n/2)+ O(1)$ since $n/2$ is half size of the heap.

?

***Update: Here is a very good Visual explanation to the recurrence:*** [http://www.cs.uvm.edu/~rsnapp/teaching/cs124/notes/cs124notes_031914.pdf](http://www.cs.uvm.edu/%7Ersnapp/teaching/cs124/notes/cs124notes_031914.pdf)

Comment: This question does not make sense as long as you don't show the (pseudo)code of $\text{MaxHeapify}$.

Comment: It is in the classical Algorithms Analysis book (introduction to algorithms) by Cormen and et al.

Comment: Implicitly referring to a charged book is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an heap of height $h \ge 1$ having $2^{h-1}$ leaves on its last level.
Let $\ell$  (resp. $r$) be the number of vertices in the subtree rooted in the left (resp. right) child of the root.

Then $\ell = 2^{h-1} + 2^{h-2} + \dots + 1 = 2^h -1$ while $r = 2^{h-2} + 2^{h-3} + \dots + 1 = 2^{h-1} -1$.
The overall number $n$ of nodes in the heap is $\ell + r + 1 = 2^h + 2^{h-1} - 1 = 3 \cdot 2^{h-1} - 1$.

If we recurse on the left subtree, the ratio between the number of  nodes of the whole heap and the number of nodes in the subtree is:
$$
\frac{\ell}{n} = \frac{2^h -1}{3 \cdot 2^{h-1} - 1} = \frac{2 \cdot 2^{h-1} -1}{3 \cdot 2^{h-1} - 1}.
$$

This ratio is always smaller than $\frac{2}{3}$.
Moreover, taking the limit as $h$, and hence $n$, grows to $+\infty$ you get (in the above construction $\ell$ and $n$ can be thought as functions of $h$):
$$
\lim_{h \to \infty} \frac{\ell}{n} = \frac{2}{3}.
$$

In other words it is always true that $\ell \le \frac{2}{3}n$ and, for any constant $c < \frac{2}{3}$ it is false that $\ell \le c n$ (for some heap with sufficiently many nodes).

Comment: If a heap has height $h$, then it should have $2^h$ leaves in the last level, where $h = \log n$, not $2^{h-1}$ leaves, ?

Comment: That's false. As a counterexample consider a heap $H$ consisting of only two nodes. The height $h$ of $H$ is $1$, but there is only one node at level $1$ (and not $2^h=2$). Using the [definitions from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree): Heaps are complete binary trees but they are not necessarily perfect binary trees.

Comment: So the number of leaves in a heap is between $2^{h-1}+1$ and $2^h$?

Comment: Yes. You can prove that by induction on $h$. For $h=0$ the claim is true since there is only one leaf and $2^{-1}\le 1\le 2^0$. For $h=1$ an heap has either $\ell \in \{1,2\}$ hence $2^{0}=1 \le \ell \le 2^1=2$. For $h>1$, let $r$ be the root of the heap and notice that it must have exactly two children. Let $u$ be its left child and let $v$ be its right child. Moreover, for $x \in \{u,v\}$ denote by $T_x$ the subtree rooted at vertex $x$. Either both the height of $T_u$ and $T_v$ are $h-1$, or the height of $T_u$ is $h-1$ while the height of $T_v$ is $h-2$ and $T_v$ is a perfect binary tree.

Comment: In the former case the number of leaves is at least $2^{h-2} + 2^{h-2} = 2^{h-1}$ and at most $2^{h-1} + 2^{h-1} = 2^h$. In the latter case the number of leaves is at least $2^{h-2} + 2^{h-2} = 2^{h-1}$ and at most $2^{h-1} + 2^{h-2} < 2^{h-1} + 2^{h-1} = 2^h$.

Comment: @Jarvis remember the definition of a heap. It is a complete binary tree with "no holes." For each level of depth, the number of leaves doubles. So the deepest level will have $≤2^h$ leaves, and $≥2^{h-1}+1$ leaves.

Comment: @devam_04. The **deepest** level can have a single leaf. But the **overall** number of leaves is between $2^{h-1}$ and $2^{h}$. This interval is tight.

Comment: Right, thanks for correcting. I meant to say that the total number of leaves *along with the deepest level* is between that.