# Having trouble calculating the asymptotic running time of MAX-HEAPIFY

Tags: asymptotics, heaps

I don't understand the $T(2n / 3)$ part in the recurrence relation for MAX-HEAPIFY in the book CLRS. There is another post that explains it but I can't realize it.

Comment: Is it clear to you that $2n/3$ must be an upper bound to the size of the subtree you are recursing in? For an explanation of the constant cannot be lower than $2/3$ you can see [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/141748/how-is-the-reccurence-of-max-heapify-tn-t2n-3-theta1/141752#141752) answer? If that's not clear, maybe you can be more explicit on what your confusion is

Comment: @Steven I have seen the answer but I haven't understood it. No I can't understand why it's an upper bound.

Comment: I'll try to write an answer showing how you can prove that.

Comment: @Steven Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you are running MAX-HEAPIFY on some vertex $v$ of a heap $H$. Then the subtree $H_v$ rooted at $v$ is also a heap. Let $n$ be the number of vertices of $H_v$.

Clearly if $v$ has no children or only one (left) children then $T(n) = O(1)$ so let's focus on the case in which $v$ has two children $u$ and $w$, where $u$ is the left child and $w$ is the right child. Let $n_u$ be the number of vertices in $H_u$ and $n_w$ be the number of vertices in $H_w$.

Clearly the worst case happens when we choose to recurse on the subtree with most nodes between $H_u$ and $H_w$. By the properties of the heap we know that $n_u \ge n_w$ so we can restrict ourselves to the case in which we recurse on $H_u$.

The question now becomes: **how large can $n_u$ be compared to $n$?**

To answer this question let $h_v$ be the height of $H_v$. We know that the height $h_u$ of $H_u$ must be $h_v - 1$. Moreover, the height of $H_w$ can be either $h_v-1$ or $h_v-2$ (otherwise $H$ was not a [complete binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees)).

The maximum number of nodes in a binary tree of a generic height $h$ is at most $2^{h+1}-1$ (which corresponds to a [perfect binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees) binary tree).
This tells us that $n_u \le 2^{h_u + 1} - 1 = 2^{h_v} - 1$.

Moreover, the number of nodes in a complete binary tree of height $h$ is at least $2^h$ (where $2^h - 1$ nodes are from a perfect binary tree of height $h-1$ and there must be at least one node on the $h$-th level).
This tells us that $n_w \ge 2^{h_w} \ge 2^{h_v-2}$.

We are now ready to find the maximum possible ratio between $n_u$ and $n = n_u + n_w + 1$.

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{n_u}{n} &= \frac{n_u}{n_u + n_w + 1} \le \frac{n_u}{n_u + 2^{h_v-2} + 1} =
1 - \frac{2^{h_v-2} + 1}{n_u + 2^{h_v-2} + 1} \\
&\le 
1 - \frac{2^{h_v-2} + 1}{2^{h_v-1} + 2^{h_v-2} + 1}
= 1 - \frac{2^{h_v-2} + 1}{3 \cdot 2^{h_v-2} + 1} \\
& < 1 - \frac{2^{h_v-2} + 1}{3 \cdot ( 2^{h_v-2} + 1)} = 1 - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{3}.
\end{align*} 
$$

Comment: Excellent. I understand now. My problem was indexing. You modified it in this new answer. Thanks.

Comment: We also get the same upper bound for MIN-HEAPIFY. Right? With the same proof.

Comment: Yes, Min-Heaps and Max-Heap are completely symmetric.

Comment: @Pallen thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a tree $\mathcal{T}$ at root  $\mathcal{r }$, and contain $\mathcal{n}$ nodes and $\mathcal{h}$ be height of $\mathcal{T}$ such that leaves are half full, so, without loss generality, suppose the left sub-tree  $\ell$ of $\mathcal{T}$ is a full binary tree (i.e. leaves are half full).

> ***(i)*** Now it's sufficient to show that ratio of  $\ell$ to $n$ (i.e. $\frac{|\ell|}{n})$ is
> $\frac{2}{3}$.

Consequently the worst case of MAX-HEAPIFY happen when  we recurse on $\ell$.

For showing (i), first of all, let  the number of nodes in $\ell$ is:
$$|\ell|=\sum_{i=0}^{\mathcal{h}-1}2^i=2^h-1$$ The number of nodes in  $\mathcal{R}:$
$$|\mathcal{R}|=\sum_{i=0}^{\mathcal{h}-2}2^i=2^{h-1}-1$$
As a result
$$n=|\ell|+|\mathcal{R}|+\mathcal{r }=|\ell|+|\mathcal{R}|+1=3\times 2^{h-1}-1$$
So
$$\frac{|\ell|}{n}= \frac{2^{h-1}-1}{3\times 2^{h-1}-1}\leq \frac{2\times2^{h-1}}{3\times 2^{h-1}}=\frac{2}{3}.$$